# What's wrong with my Angular 2 app (TypeScript)

Tags: angular, web-applications, typescript, angular2-directives

I have a component **EventListComponent**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component ({
    selector: 'el-events',
    templateUrl: 'app/events/event-list.component.html'
})

export class EventListComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'Events List';
}
```

which should be rendered in **AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { EventListComponent } from './events/event-list.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'events-app',
    template: `
    <div>
        <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
        <el-events></el-events>
    </div>`,
    directives: [ EventListComponent ]
})

export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'Local Events App';
}
```

Directives, selectors, import/export and entire decorator is setuped correclty, IDE says.
Yes, I use old Angular 2 version with directives, that's a course requirements.

So, there's a problem - page doesn't show components. Here are errors:
[image]

And project tree is this:

[image]

I discovered that error happens when I add **directives**, so maybe problem is here. Angular version is:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15"
}
```

**UPD**
Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Local Events App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="app/app.component.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <events-app>
        Loading App...
    </events-app>
</body>

</html>
```

**event-list.component.html**

```
<div class 'panel panel-primary'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        {{pageTitle}}
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-2'></div>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <h3>Search by: </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='table-responsive'>
        <table class='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <button class='btn btn-primary'>
                            Show image
                        </button>
                    </th>
                    <th>Event</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Fee</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does your event list component html looks like?seems you have missed some tags there..

Comment: @MadhuRanjan that's how - http://localeventsapp-kenyawest.c9users.io/

Comment: Can you show your index.html ?

Comment: Add code inside `event-list.component.html`

Comment: @MadhuRanjan added! Also I can give you access to my project if needed...

Comment: `System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));` why? change it to  `System.import('app')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `=` in your **event-list.component.html**

```
<div class 'panel panel-primary'>
```

It should be

```
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
```

Comment: YOU ARE A WIZARD! Thank you! This stupid C9 Cloud IDE doesn't validate HTML huh

Comment: @yurzui  Eagle-Eyes !